# jQuery getting the closest div with a class

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Hii i want to show the number chars to the closest div with the class `showchars`.

I tried to do this :

```
$('#maina').focus(function() {
$(this).closest("div.showchars").find(".countchars").html("KKK");
    $("#error-1").html("");
    $(this).closest(".showchars").html("hmm");
});
```

With this html:

```
    <tr>
    <td>
    Main Alliase/Current Alliase:
    </td>
    <td><input type="text" id="maina" class="countchars"/><br />
    <div class="showchars">o</div>
    </td>
<td><span id="handle-1" class="selector">?</span></td>
    <td><div id="error-1" class="errors"></div></td>
    </tr>
```

When i focus into the input boxes it does resets the content of the errors class.

But doesnt changes text to : `hmm` in the div.

Where have been i going wrong or what is the better way to get the closest div and then implement the api : `.html("hmm")` ?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) **looks at the element itself and its parents for a match**.

In your example, `.showchars` is a sibling of the textbox so you could use [`.siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) instead.

```
$(this).siblings(".showchars").html("hmm");
```

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/FSUzR/).

Comment: It worked but will it change the content of all siblings in the class or what ? Thanks

Comment: `.siblings()` optionally accepts a filter. You can specify `".showchars"` to filter the element you precisely need.

Comment: Yea i know that but i mean to say that it will put that to all siblings found with class showchars ? Just asking if i can implement it somewhere else too

Comment: Yes and no, depending on what you're asking. If the source element has more than one siblings with the class `showchars`, all of them will contain that text. You can use `.showchars:first` as the filter to target the first sibling, `.showchars:eq(1)` for the second and so on.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(this).nextAll(".showchars:first").html("hmm");
```

Comment: I dont think getting all the next and then selecting the first is a good option. Thought Thanks for trying :D

Comment: Ill rather use the .sibling :D

Comment: `siblings` would also get all sibling and filter them with selector