# Show div after button click jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

Hi I try to show a `div` element in jQuery mobile when the user touch the button. I already created own classes for the button and for the div element, but nothing happens. What classes should I take?

JS:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
 $(".commentbtn").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // in some browsers a button submits if no type=
    $(this).siblings("div.comment").toggle();
});
});
```

CSS:

```
.comment {
    display:none;
}
```

HTML:

```
<?php foreach ($result as $key => $row): ?>
    <div class="ui-btn-text">
        <button class="commentbtn" data-rel="button">comment</button>
        <div id="createcomment" class="comment" data-theme="a">
            <form data-ajax="false" name="login-form" class="login-form" action="./comments.php" method="post" style="padding:20px 40px;">
                <div class="content">
                    <textarea rows="1" name="text" id="text" class="foo"></textarea>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Wheres the element with class `.btn-info`? if it does not exist, then your click event is useless.

Comment: You fire an event on .btn-info click, but there is no element with the class btn-info in your HTML.

Comment: Could you please leave out the PHP and paste only the affected parts of the output of the PHP?

Comment: PHP tag applied to be removed.

Comment: Also, in your code I only see one element with class `comment`, which means that your click function wont work since your code assumes there are multiple `comment` classes: `.closest(".comment").children(".comment")`,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't got any `element` with the class `.btn-info` so you wouldn't be able to call the event from:

```
  $(".btn-info").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // in some browsers a button submits if no type=
    $(this).closest(".comment").children(".comment").show();
  });
```

You have an element with the class `.commentbtn` which you would then do the same as you did with the `.btn-info`

```
  $(".commentbtn").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // in some browsers a button submits if no type=
    // Console log the element
    console.log($(this).closest(".comment").children(".comment"));
    // Console log not showing the right element. So you need to get the 
    // sibling of the clicked button
    // Instead of doing - $(this).closest(".comment").children(".comment").show();
    // You can do the following
    $(this).siblings("div.comment").show();
  });
```

`.closest()` - looks at the element itself and its parents for a match.

`.siblings` - Get the siblings of each element in the set of matched elements, optionally filtered by a selector.

[**Example With `.show();`**](https://jsfiddle.net/z0Lpovyr/5/)

Here an example with `.toggle();` If you wanted to show/hide the comment with same button. (Just little extra for you to look at)

[**Example With `.toggle();`**](https://jsfiddle.net/z0Lpovyr/6/)

**UPDATE:**

[**Example with `.comment` shown on load**](https://jsfiddle.net/z0Lpovyr/7/)

Comment: Thank you, that works but when I load my page, the div become shown, how can I change it that the div only after the click, how in your fiddles, become shown? :)

Comment: @klamertd Which `div` are you talking about?

Comment: About this:`<div id="createcomment" class="comment" data-theme="a">` I have the script in my head and edit it a bit. The div becomes after pageload showed.

Comment: @klamertd If you look at both my examples, you will see that it's not shown on page load, and it only shows on button clicked

Comment: Yes in your examples works it right but in my case its the other way around. ;) How can I change that or how can I show it first and after button click hide in your examples?

Comment: @klamertd Take look at my updated example, it will be shown on load, hidden on button click.

Answer (score 2):

Your button has class commentbtn, so you should use that instead of btn-info.  Also, you should be looking for the [sibling div,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6895056/jquery-getting-the-closest-div-with-a-class) not the closest.

```
$(".commentbtn").on("click", function(e) {
   e.preventDefault(); // in some browsers a button submits if no type=
   $(this).siblings("div.comment").show();
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cq1mz2bo/) demo